# Laravel mysql select count of joined table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table with a list of users (`users`). I have a pivot table (`sign_in_out`) with fields `user_id` and `signed_in`. I want to get a list of **all** the users with their respective counts of how many `sign_in_out` rows contain a `NULL` value.

This is what I have now:

```
$publishers = Sentry::getUserProvider()
    ->createModel()
    ->select('users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'sio.sign_in_count')
    ->join('users_groups', 'users.id', '=', 'users_groups.user_id')
    ->join(DB::raw('(
        SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) sign_in_count
        FROM sign_in_out
        WHERE signed_in IS NULL
        GROUP BY user_id) sio'), function($join)
    {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'sio.user_id');
    })
    ->where('users_groups.group_id', '=', 2)
    ->orderBy('users.last_name', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('users.first_name', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

This returns only results where `signed_in` is `NULL` along with the `count` of how many times it occurs but I want to return all users regardless if they have any any matching rows in the `sign_in_out` table or not. I know `WHERE signed_in IS NULL` is gumming this up so how do I isolate that away from the main query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - query should have been using a `left join` when querying the `sio` table:

```
$publishers = Sentry::getUserProvider()
    ->createModel()
    ->select('users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'sio.sign_in_count')
    ->join('users_groups', 'users.id', '=', 'users_groups.user_id')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(
        SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) sign_in_count
        FROM sign_in_out
        WHERE signed_in IS NULL
        GROUP BY user_id) sio'), function($join)
    {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'sio.user_id');
    })
    ->where('users_groups.group_id', '=', 2)
    ->orderBy('users.last_name', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('users.first_name', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```